# How to avoid ordering issues for concurrent requests from the same user?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, race-condition

Suppose you have a system that processes requests concurrently having as an end result storing a field in the database. Now suppose the following scenario appears, where `id` the request id, `user` is the user that made the call, `val` is the value being stored in the database and `t` is the time:

```
Client                          Server                       Database
   | id=1, user=x, val=100, t=1   |                             |
   |----------------------------> |                             |
   | id=2, user=x, val=50,  t=2   |                             |
   |----------------------------> | id=2, user=x, val=50, t=3   |
   |                              |---------------------------->| 
   |                              | id=1, user=x, val=100, t=4  |
   |                              |---------------------------->|
```

The problem is that the same user makes two requests at almost the same time, but due to out-of-order execution of tasks in the server, the last request is processed first and this value is inserted in the database, while the first request comes and overrides this data finally leaving the database in an inconsistent state.

I've thought of two solutions:

1. Add a `creation_time` field in the database and only update if `objectToBeInserted.creationTimestamp > objectAlreadyInDb.creationTimestamp`. This has limited usage however; suppose that instead of the database there is another system to whom you should make the request and thus you cannot query the database.
2. User a `Map` of `userId` associated with a `semaphore`. When a request arrives check if the semaphore corresponding to this user is taken; if is taken then wait otherwise proceed. After inserting in the db, release the semaphore. However this has the limitation of not being able to process requests concurrently from the same user and also might have memory issues if there are many users but in the happy case is faster (only one db call).

Are these solution good enough or is there a better typical solution for this problem?

Comment: "However this has the limitation of not being able to process requests concurrently from the same user" - isn't this what you want? If the order matters then you want to process the requests sequentially. BTW - is request id an actual parameter in the request that guarantees the correct ordering? Because I don't think you can guarantee that the second request arrives last to the server.

Comment: Instead of an imprecise time value (which can jump forward and backward in time), have the client generate an update sequence number and only write if a higher number is received. Wouldn't this work?

Comment: @mp_ Order of processing is irrelevant; only what is saved in the db mathers.

Comment: @m3th0dman yes, but imagine a situation where the client message does not have an id attribute. How will you tell which message was sent first? If the messages are sent concurrently by the client then the second message may arrive first. Even if the second message is sent second, if the client uses separate tcp connections to send them then the message could arrive first. Or did I misunderstand and there is some kind of guarantee that the messages arrive in order?

Comment: @mp_ Messages arrive in order, guaranteed by protocol. Messages are not processed in order by server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most typical solution is to add a sequence number. Or you could use a MQ software that guarantees ordered processing (these usually use sequence numbers internally to guarantee ordering). Using a MQ is probably a good idea as it's easy to stall the processing should you lose a message (if you lose msg #2, #3, #4 won't be processed etc.), and MQs come with mechanisms to prevent message loss.

**EDIT**: There is a good discussion in this [article](https://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Transactional-topologies.html) that explains different designs. To your question, the 3rd endpoint must provide transactions, but as long as it does it doesn't have to be a DB.

Comment: I cannot change neither the client nor the protocol.

Comment: @m3th0dman: You could still assign a sequence number at the entry point of your server. If the client is single threaded and synchronous, that'll still work.

Comment: This still has the limitation that you need to query the current sequence number. And if the 3rd endpoint is another system and not a database, can this still be implemented?

Comment: You could store the sequence number in the server memory (attach a sequence number to the request as it arrives and store the highest sequence number per client in memory). If the server crashes, loosing the sequence number, then all connections and unprocessed request will be dropped anyway.